# Ruby on Rails 3 Select Helper Question

Tags: forms, select, ruby-on-rails-3

Have have this line of code in my form when I create a new item. Though when I edit the item, the default selection isn't the one that is selected. Do  I need to set the initial value?

```
<%= f.select :category, options_for_select(Item::CATEGORIES) %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`options_for_select` accepts second param which identifies the selected value.

try

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Item::CATEGORIES, :downcase, :titleize %>
```

It assumes your `Item::CATEGORIES` gives a array of strings of categories.

for each category in `Item::CATEGORIES`, `category.downcase` will be used as the option's value, while `category.titleize` will be used as the option's text.

ie.

```
<option value="<%= cate.downcase %>"><%= cate.titleize %></option>
```

======

or you could:

```
<%= f.select :category, options_for_select(Item::CATEGORIES, @cur_obj.category.id) %>
```